# Angular 1.x typescript "TypeError: "Uploader" must be an instance of FileUploader"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I have been trying to use the angular-file-upload here https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload with typescript, and I keep getting this error:

TypeError: "Uploader" must be an instance of FileUploader
I have to put a declare module and export namespace on the actual angular-file-upload to use modules(since that is how our framework was built) but I can't seem to go past this error

Don't worry about the module initialization or namespace names etc I should put placeholders there to not show our actual code.

Code below:

```js
/// <reference types="angular" />
/// <reference types="angular-ui-bootstrap" />
/// <reference types="angular-file-upload"/>

var bootbox: any;

module MyModule.module {
    export class MyController  {
      
                

        static $inject = [
            "$scope",
            "$q",
            "$state",           
            "FileUploader"
               
        ];

        constructor(private scope: any,
            private promiseService: angular.IQService,
            private stateService: angular.ui.IStateService,          
            private uploader: angular.file.upload.FileUploader
            )                      
        {

            this.uploader.url = "upload.php";

            this.scope.uploader = this.uploader
}

(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("myApp").controller("app.mymodule.controller", Namespace.MyApp.MyController);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="vm.uploader" /><br />

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
    Name: <span ng-bind="item.file.name"></span><br />
    <button ng-click="item.upload()">upload</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue, I was not using the interfaces correctly. Here is the correct code:

```js
constructor(private scope: any,
  private fileUploaderFactory: angular.file.upload.FileUploaderFactory) {


  this.scope.uploader = new fileUploaderFactory({
    url: 'upload.php'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the `FileUploader` with `new angular.file.upload.FileUploader()`

Comment: on the private uploader under the constructor signature? if yes that does not work lol

Comment: Whoops, my bad, did you try using new operator on the uploader in the class body? Or is the error happening on init?

Comment: yes I tried the one in the example but I guess since I am using example it is different, when I use the new I get an error that says Cannot use new with an expression whose type lacks  a call or construct signature.

Comment: And what is the value that this.uploader has?

Comment: it does seem to be the fileuploader that I am setting it to, which is exported from the library. I do see all the methods like uploadAll, isHtml5 etc when i do a "this.uploader."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the key issue seems to be then the error `Cannot use new with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`. If try you simply assigning new this.uploader to simplest variable, as soon as possible after constructor, doest it still throw the same error?

Comment: ok i did this right after the constructor signature.

  this.uploader = new angular.file.upload.FileUploader()

and i get a red line under file saying (TS)Property 'file'does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'

Comment: I meant something like `let test = new this.uploader ` there. Referencing it like you did outside constructor will expectedly couse this problem that you had

Comment: I am only referencing it inside the constructor. I think I misunderstood you initial question. But yes I am not putting it in the class body the reference as shown in my snippet is inside the constructor

Comment: Should have been more specific - I meant "referencing it outside of constructor parameters". Please try `let test = new this.uploader ` inside the constructor body and see if there is any issue with using the `new` operator there

Comment: understood. I did and I get the same error on the new operator

Comment: Then it seems I'm not able to help, sorry about that :/ Wish I was better versed in TS to investigate properly